# How do I add JavaScript to an Object in Unity?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

**You can skip this**: I could do research but a YouTuber Recommended asking a fourm group for help. I guess the reason for this is to get more knowledge then just finding the answer without thinking about any other variables.

---

**Question:** I was wondering how I add a Javascript File to my object in Unity. I am new to Unity and the only coding knowledge I have is in JavaScript (Although limited from 1 year of basic programming and 1 year of AP computer Science) not C#.

**What I Tried:** I have tried dragging the JavaScript File to the object in the hierarchy but that seems to not work. Is there a specific route I should take?

Comment: Unity only supported UnityScript (which was similar to JavaScript), but that support has been [removed](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/08/11/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset/). The only supported language now is C#

Comment: Yep this is deprecated since `Unity 2018.2` .. either use an older version or start learning `C#` .. it is not that different from that `UnityScript` flavour of `JavaScript` which might be one of the reasons why this is deprecated now ;)